# Linear programming - MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I've a [8x4] matrix, 'A', and a [8x1] matrix, 'B'. How do I check if there exists a [4x1] matrix 'x' such that `A * X = B`?

This can be done using `linprog` in MATLAB, but I'm  not sure how to give the constraints. I tried `x = linprog([],[],[],A,B);`, but this doesn't seem to work.

How to specify the condition `x>=0` and optimize it for `A*X-B` so that, if it returns 0, we know there is `X`.

**Update:**

`pinv` in MATLAB doesn't work in all the cases. Consider the following example:

```
A= [1     0     0     0
     0     1    -1    -1
    -1    -1     1    -1
    -1    -1    -1     1
     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0
     1     1     1     1]
B = [0
     0
     0
    -1
     0
     0
     0
     1]
```

using `pinv` gives the the value of X as:

```
X = [-2.7756e-017
    0.5000
    0.5000
         0]
```

but when linear programming is used I get x as:

```
X = [    0
    0.5000
    0.5000
         0]
```

This is the reason why I preferred `linprog` tool in MATLAB. I just used it the way I mentioned previously but it is throwing a lot of warnings. I still think there is a better way to use this function correctly. It did not throw for this matrix but in general when I loop through a lot of matrices my command window overflow with warnings.

Answer (score 2):

Why use linear programming? You can just solve the system `A*x=B` directly:

```
A =[ 1    -1    -1    -1     1     0     0     1
    -1     1    -1     0     0     1     0     0
    -1    -1     1     0     1     0     0     0
    -1    -1    -1     1     1     1     0     0]'; %'# 

B = [-1    -1     0     0     0     0     1     1]'; %'#

x = A\B
x =
      0.16327
     0.097959
      0.46531
      0.11837
```

The problem you may face is that `A` can be rank deficient, but in that case, you'll get infinitely many solutions for `x`.

Comment: That is the main problem. What I do now is if ( (A * pinv(A) * B) == B) then there exists a solution. where pinv is pseudo inverse function in matlab. I think linear programming handles this condition well. That's why I'm looking for a way to do that.

Comment: No, you don't know that is true. It is a rare case where such a test for EXACT equality will EVER be true when applied in floating point arithmetic! Use of linprog to try to do that test is silly.

Answer (score 2):

But why use a code that will do MORE work than necessary to solve the problem? Just use the pseudo-inverse. If A is of full rank, then backslash will be entirely sufficient.

Compute the solution. If the norm of your residuals is less than some tolerance, then you have a solution. Note that essentially no solution is ever assured to give you truly zero residuals, so you must apply a tolerance. Thus

```
x = A\B;
if norm(B - A*x) < tol
  disp('Eureeka!')
end
```

Or use `x=pinv(A)*B` if you are worried about the rank of A.

Trying to throw linprog at the problem will surely not be more efficient than the direct solution itself.

Edit: Since non-negativity of the result has now been added as a requirement, use lsqnonneg instead. Just compare the norm of the residual vector to a tolerance. If the norm is too large, then no solution exists.

Comment: I tried x=pinv(A)*B but it doesnt give me any solution but when I used linprog it gives me solution but throws in a exception at each iteration (I have many A's). the exception is: (1)Exiting due to infeasibility: an all-zero row in the constraint
 matrix does not have a zero in corresponding right-hand-side entry. (2) Exiting: One or more of the residuals, duality gap, or total relative error has stalled: the primal appears to be infeasible (and the dual unbounded).(The dual residual < TolFun=1.00e-008.)

Comment: You should also look at the condition X>=0 which is very important.

Comment: ARGH. You now change the problem as posed, adding in non-negativity of the result as a requirement.

Comment: Sorry for a late reply. The non-negative condition was always there in my original question. Wasn't it ?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can not use array division. This is not the same a matrix division. However, you could use the inverse of the Matrix A to multiply it with matrix B to get x x = (A-1)B, but I am not sure if an inverse is possible for non-square matrix A (8x4). Hence, you might not have been able to work that with linprog

Comment: Pseudo inverse always exists and that's how I'm doing it now. Please see my comments to jonas about how I'm doing it now.